# NodeJS, MongoDB - How to concat 2 streams to one and send the result as one array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, streaming, nodejs-stream, node.js-fs

I have been encountering an issue for a long time but I haven't found any solution yet,
despite reading other answers that related to this issue.

I have 2 different mongo dbs and I want to concat 2 streams that came from each one,
and send the result to the client.

The problem is that the response contains 2 arrays (the first of db1, the second of db2)
instead of one array that contains the data of both.

How can I concat the 2 arrays in the response into one array?

In order to simulate the problem I did the same with files.

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const CombinedStream = require('combined-stream');
const MultiStream = require('multistream');
const JSONStream = require('jsonstream-next');
const app = express();

function concatStreams(streams) {
  var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
  streams.forEach(stream => combinedStream.append(stream));
  return combinedStream;
};

function createDbStream(connection, dbName, colName1, colName2){
  const collection = connection.useDb(dbName).db.collection(colName1);
  const pipeline = [ 
    {$match: {}},
    {$project: { _id: 1, value: 1 }},
    {$unionWith: {
        coll: colName2,
        pipeline: [ {$match: {}}, {$project: { _id: 1, value: 1 }} ]
      }
    }
  ];
  const stream = collection.aggregate(pipeline).stream()
    .pipe(JSONStream.stringify());
  return stream;
}

async function getDbStreams(){
  const connection1 = await mongoose.createConnection("dburl1",  { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, });
  const connection2 = await mongoose.createConnection("dburl2", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, });
  const stream1 = createDbStream(connection1, "dbName", "colName1", "colName2");
  const stream2 = createDbStream(connection2, "dbName", "colName1", "colName2");
  return [stream1, stream2];
}

app.post('/concat-file-stream1', (req, res) => {
  const filePaths = ["/file1.json", "/file2.json"];
  const streams = filePaths.map(path=>fs.createReadStream(path));
  const result = concatStreams(streams);
  result.pipe(res.type('json'));
});

app.post('/concat-file-stream2', (req, res) => {
  const filePaths = ["/file1.json", "/file2.json"];
  const streams = filePaths.map(path=>fs.createReadStream(path));
  const result = MultiStream(streams)
  result.pipe(res.type('json'));
});

app.post('/concat-db-stream1', async (req, res) => {
  const streams = await getDbStreams();
  const result = concatStreams(streams);
  result.pipe(res.type('json'));
});

app.post('/concat-db-stream2', async (req, res) => {
  const streams = await getDbStreams();
  const result = new MultiStream(streams);
  result.pipe(res.type('json'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${3000}.`);
});
```

My files:

file1.json:

```
[
  { "id": "1", "value": 1 },
  { "id": "2", "value": 2 },
  { "id": "3", "value": 3 }
]
```

file2.json:

```
[
  { "id": "4", "value": 4 },
  { "id": "5", "value": 5 },
  { "id": "6", "value": 6 }
]
```

The response:

[image: response]